# Saving attachments either returns 91 error or does not save

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to set up a macro in ThisOutlookSession to save attachments to file.

I previously used rules and 'run a script', but it is not enabled for all users.

The below code either returns a 91 error (object or variable not set), or it runs without error, but doesn't save.

The code is looking at a subfolder, to save all attachments to a location based on subject. The emails are sent to the subfolder through a rule.

I want to rename the attachments based on the ReceivedTime, and I think this is where the issue arises. If I use Msg.ReceivedTime, I get the 91 error. If I use Item.ReceivedTime, there is no error, but the file is not saved.

Here is the source where I derived most of the code and customized. https://www.tachytelic.net/2017/10/how-to-run-a-vba-macro-when-new-mail-is-received-in-outlook/

```
Private WithEvents folderItems As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
  Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
  Dim objectNS As Outlook.NameSpace

  Set outlookApp = Outlook.Application
  Set objectNS = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  Set folderItems = objectNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Operations").Folders("Test").Items
End Sub

Private Sub folderItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
Dim att As Outlook.Attachment
Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim filepath As String, filedate As String
filepath = "C:\Documents\"
filedate = Format(Item.ReceivedTime, "YYYYMMDD") 'This is the line which I think is the problem. If I do Msg.ReceivedTime, I get 91 error, but if I do Item.ReceivedTime, it does not save
If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then
    If InStr(Item.Subject, "XXX") > 0 Then
        For Each att In Item.Attachments
            att.SaveAsFile filepath & "XXX\" & filedate & "_raw.csv"
        Next
   ElseIf InStr(Item.Subject, "YYY") > 0 Then
        For Each att In Item.Attachments
            att.SaveAsFile filepath & "YYY\" & filedate & "_raw.xlsx"
        Next
    ElseIf InStr(Item.Subject, "ZZZ") > 0 Then
        For Each att In Item.Attachments
            att.SaveAsFile filepath & "ZZZ.csv"
        Next
    End If
End If
ExitNewItem:
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Resume ExitNewItem
End Sub
```

My hypothesis is that the ReceivedTime is the issue. If I can use Msg.ReceivedTime, how do I set the variable? Or, if Item.ReceivedTime is correct, why does it not save?

Comment: The issue is- item is nothing - you will have to assign set item to a reference

Comment: How do I assign a reference to Item? I want the Item to refer to every new mail coming into this folder.

Comment: See answer below and let me know- Thanks

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Try the following*

```
Dim att As Outlook.attachment
Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim filepath As String, filedate As String

filepath = "C:\Documents\"

If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then
    Set msg = Item
    Debug.Print msg.ReceivedTime ' print on Immediate Window
    filedate = Format(msg.ReceivedTime, "YYYYMMDD")

    If InStr(msg.Subject, "XXX") > 0 Then
        For Each att In msg.Attachments
            att.SaveAsFile filepath & "XXX\" & filedate & "_raw.csv"
        Next
   ElseIf InStr(msg.Subject, "YYY") > 0 Then
        For Each att In msg.Attachments
            att.SaveAsFile filepath & "YYY\" & filedate & "_raw.xlsx"
        Next
    ElseIf InStr(msg.Subject, "ZZZ") > 0 Then
        For Each att In msg.Attachments
            att.SaveAsFile filepath & "ZZZ.csv"
        Next
    End If
End If
```

*also you don't need `outlookApp` when the code is running within Outlook Application, simply use Application.*

*Example*

```
Private Sub Application_Startup()
  Dim objectNS As Outlook.NameSpace

  Set objectNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  Set folderItems = objectNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox) _
                            .Folders("Operations") _
                            .Folders("Test").Items
End Sub
```